# Find Sunday and Monday with NSCalendar Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nscalendar

Hi all I am working on a calendar using `NSCalendar`.

I need to find every **Sunday** and **Monday** within the month to change the cell color unlike other days ..

Can you help me understand how to find (through the use of `NSCalendar`) every **Sunday** and **Monday** of the current month?

Comment: You have tagged the question with Swift so you should be using `Calendar` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all the date of the monday of current month in ios sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882242/get-all-the-date-of-the-monday-of-current-month-in-ios-sdk), scroll down for a swift solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the start end end of the month, enumerate all days in a month (you can use noon), check if the resulting day is less than the end date otherwise stop the enumeration. Then you just need to check if the date's weekday is equal to Sunday or Monday (1 or 2) and add it to the collection:

---

```
extension Date {
    func startOfMonth(using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Date {
        calendar.dateComponents([.calendar, .year, .month], from: self).date!
    }
    func startOfNextMonth(using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Date {
        calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: startOfMonth(using: calendar))!
    }
    func weekday(using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Int {
        calendar.component(.weekday, from: self)
    }
}
```

---

```
let now = Date()
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
let start = now.startOfMonth(using: calendar)
let end = now.startOfNextMonth(using: calendar)
var dates: [Date] = []

calendar.enumerateDates(startingAfter: start, matching: DateComponents(hour: 12), matchingPolicy: .strict) { (date, _, stop) in
    guard let date = date, date < end else {
        stop = true
        return
    }
    if 1...2 ~= date.weekday(using: calendar) { dates.append(date) }
}

dates.forEach {
    print($0.description(with: .current))
}
```

---

This will print

> Sunday, October 4, 2020 at 12:00:00 PM BRST
> Monday, October 5, 2020 at 12:00:00 PM BRST
> Sunday, October 11, 2020 at 12:00:00 PM BRST
> Monday, October 12, 2020 at 12:00:00 PM BRST
> Sunday, October 18, 2020 at 12:00:00 PM BRST
> Monday, October 19, 2020 at 12:00:00 PM BRST
> Sunday, October 25, 2020 at 12:00:00 PM BRST
> Monday, October 26, 2020 at 12:00:00 PM BRST

Comment: thanks you very much Leo! This is beauty! Thanks again

Comment: Hi Leo sorry .. if I need to read a third element instead of 2 how could I modify your example to show Sunday, Monday, Tuesday?

Comment: `if 1...3 ~= date.weekday...`

Comment: sorry, maybe I explained myself wrong in asking the question .. If I needed to get not consecutive days but for example only Sunday or Tuesday only I would have to create two different arrays to contain the days of Sunday and Tuesday

Comment: It is still unclear what you are asking but all you need is to create an array with the desired weekdays (Sunday=1...Saturday=7) `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` and check if it contains the date weekday `[1,3].contains(date.weekday(using: calendar))`